# C# WPF datagrid row background color

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the below simplified code to color certain rows of my DataGrid. I would like to do this task programmatically and not through XAML.

```
public IEnumerable<System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid)
{
    var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
        if (null != row) yield return row;
    }
}

public void color()
{
    var rows = GetDataGridRows(dg1);

    foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
    {
        //DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)r.Item;

        //remove code for simplicity

        r.Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100, 100));
    }
}
```

Doing this does not change the background of the row.

Comment: Why doing this via code if there are better and easier ways doing it in xaml?

Comment: I already have the function working in Winforms, so I am trying to directly convert it. I'm sure its an easy fix in my code above, one that im not seeing.

Comment: I would recommend using xaml for this because WPF isn't winforms and the way you should develop WPF is different then winforms. Just my two cents

Comment: Do you want to change the row color depending on the content of a certain cell-value?

Comment: Basically I want to compare two datagrids, each with one column, and change the row color of rows that are not in the other datagrid.

Comment: Have you tried r.Background = Brushes.Black (or whatever colour you want), just did a quick test and it seemed to work fine

Comment: That's weird. I get the error "Application error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work unless you display very few rows in your `DataGrid` or disable the UI virtualization (which of course may lead to performance issues).

The correct way do change the background colour of the rows in a `DataGrid` in WPF is to define a `RowStyle`, preferably in XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#64646464" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Trying to just "convert" your Windows Forms code as-is is certainly a wrong approach. WPF and Windows Forms are two different frameworks/technologies and you don't do things the same way in both. Then it would be pretty much useless to convert in the first place.

Comment: Yeah I know my approach isn't the best, but I had assumed that my method would have worked and in the interest of time I chose that method. Your code works of course, but my issue is that my scenario is a little more complicated that what I had posted above. I need to compare two datagrids (1 column each), and color the rows that are missing from each red. I believe I would need Datatriggers and binding.

Comment: @nerdalert Comparisation of two `DataGrid`s can be done easiely with a ViewModel approach, comparing both bound lists on `DataGrid.ItemsSource`. Simple comparisation of two lists. You can add a boolean value or `Color` in the model contained in the list and do the rest in XAML. <1h